# What is the proper way to free and terminate a thread which uses the TIdTCPClient component?

Tags: delphi, indy

I'm using Delphi 10 Seattle to build a simple Client/Server application using the `TIdTCPClient`and `TIdTCPServer` components.

For read the data arrived from the server application (TIdTCPServer) I'm using a Thread in the Client Application.

This is the Execute method

```
procedure TClientReadThread.Execute;
begin
  while not Terminated do
  begin
    try      
      if FClient.Connected() then //FClient is TIdTCPClient
      begin
       if not FClient.IOHandler.InputBufferIsEmpty then
       begin
         AResponse := FClient.IOHandler.ReadLn();
         Synchronize(NotifyReadln);
       end
       else
       FClient.IOHandler.CheckForDataOnSource(10);
      end;

    except
      on E: Exception do
      begin
        // Send the exception message to the logger
        FE:=E;
        Synchronize(LogException);
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Under normal circumstances all is working fine, but now I'm doing some tests to restore the connection on the client application in case which the server or the network is down. So I shutdown the server App to simulate a issue when the comm fails.

When that happens the client application detects which the server is gone using the `TIdTCPClient.OnStatus` event.

After that I try to terminate the reading thread using this code

```
  if Assigned(FClientReadThr) then
  begin
    FClientReadThr.Terminate;
    FClientReadThr.WaitFor; // This never returns.
    FreeAndNil(FClientReadThr);
  end;
```

But the `WaitFor` function never returns.

SO the question is , there is something wrong on my execute procedure which is preventing the finalization of the thread?

Exist a better way to terminate the thread?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you should not be using `Connected()` in this manner.  Just call `ReadLn()` unconditionally and let it raise an exception if an error/disconnect occurs:

```
procedure TClientReadThread.Execute;
begin
  while not Terminated do
  begin
    try      
     AResponse := FClient.IOHandler.ReadLn();
     Synchronize(NotifyReadln);
    except
      // ...
    end;
  end;
end;
```

If you want to poll the socket for data manually, it should look more like this:

```
procedure TClientReadThread.Execute;
begin
  while not Terminated do
  begin
    try      
     if FClient.IOHandler.InputBufferIsEmpty then
     begin
       FClient.IOHandler.CheckForDataOnSource(10);
       FClient.IOHandler.CheckForDisconnect;
       if FClient.IOHandler.InputBufferIsEmpty then Continue;
     end;
     AResponse := FClient.IOHandler.ReadLn();
     Synchronize(NotifyReadln);
    except
      // ...
    end;
  end;
end;
```

DO NOT use the `TIdTCPClient.OnStatus` event to detect a disconnect in this situation.  You are deadlocking your code if you are terminating the thread directly in the `OnStatus` event handler.  That event will be called in the context of the thread, since the thread is the one reading the connection and detecting the disconnect.  So your thread ends up waiting on itself, that is why `WaitFor()` does not exit.

I would suggest an alternative approach.  DON'T terminate the thread at all.  To recover the connection, add another level of looping to the thread and let it detect the disconnect and reconnect automatically:

```
procedure TClientReadThread.Execute;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  while not Terminated do
  begin
    try      
      // don't call Connect() in the main thread anymore, do it here instead
      FClient.Connect;
    except
      // Send the exception message to the logger

      // you should wait a few seconds before attempting to reconnect,
      // don't flood the network with connection requests...
      for I := 1 to 5 do
      begin
        if Terminated then Exit;
        Sleep(1000);
      end;

      Continue;
    end;

    try
      try
        while not Terminated do
        begin
          AResponse := FClient.IOHandler.ReadLn();
          Synchronize(NotifyReadln);
        end;
      except
        // Send the exception message to the logger
      end;
    finally
      FClient.Disconnect;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

You can then `Terminate()` and `WaitFor()` the thread normally when you want to stop using your socket I/O.